# can any one will help me to remove stopwords from my mysql tweets database

Tags: java, mysql, full-text-search

for a java project i am collecting tweets from twitter, i have collected about 30,000 tweets so far and going to collect more, i want to remove stopwords from those tweets and filter them to another mirror datatbase by removing the stopwords, can anyone help me with this, thanks. If i download some list of stopwords, and check for each tweets it will take too much time, if there any other efficient way to do it, and also i did not found .txt of list of stopwords, please help me with this.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Have you run some tests? How do you know how long it will take? If you haven't found a list of stopwords, I don't see how you could have gotten any benchmarks.

Comment: so you messed with `ft_stopword_file` ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD;` , using these only 36 stopwords are coming but there are more, i need to add more stopwords into that table, for that i need list of standard stopwords, can anyone give me link to some .csv or .txt

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of stopwords, and read [This Page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) from the mysql manual.

> To override the default stopword list, set the ft_stopword_file system
>   variable. (See Section 5.1.4, “Server System Variables”.) The variable
>   value should be the path name of the file containing the stopword
>   list, or the empty string to disable stopword filtering. The server
>   looks for the file in the data directory unless an absolute path name
>   is given to specify a different directory. After changing the value of
>   this variable or the contents of the stopword file, restart the server
>   and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes.

Your 36 words you mentioned refer to those `stop words` baked into the mysql daemon upon it getting compiled, and may be representative of the topic described on [This Page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) in the manual.